# Active Directory Question

Tags: 7, entities, authentication-authorization

I am currently building an intranet site with drupal 7. It is hosted on a Windows 2012 Server R2 with IIS and I am using MSSQL 2012 as a database system. Moreover I have integrated the intranet site with Active Directory 2012 R2 and I can login with my ldap credentials.

Now I am trying to manage the following: I want a user to be already logged in to the intranet portal when he opens his web browser and not asking for his credentials again. For that reason I installed ldap_sso module. When I try to open the browser, I get a 500 error as the system tries to insert a NULL value to uid in the sessions table and this is not permitted.

Any ideas?